# How to splice nested array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

> result of my query

```
absent: 0
attn: {21: {days: 5}, 22: {days: 5}, 23: {days: 3}}
daily_rate: 57.50798722044728
deduction: {4: {amount: 333.33}, 6: {amount: 222.2, },…}
4: {amount: 333.33,}
6: {amount: 222.2}
7: {amount: 2242}
8: {amount: 1127.5}
9: {amount: 1120}
```

> In my vue js I have parent array and child array..I have no idea how to splice data in nested array

```
                     <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(fetch, count) in payrollPayableArray">  -----> PARENT ARRAY
                     <td style="height:10px;">{{fetch.pay_class}}</td>
                     <td style="height:10px; color:red;">{{formatNum(fetch.absent * fetch.daily_rate)}}</td>
                     <td style="height:10px; color:red;">{{formatNum(fetch.late * fetch.rate_per_minute)}}</td>
                     <td style="height:10px; color:red;">{{formatNum(fetch.ut * fetch.rate_per_minute)}}</td>
                     <td style="height:10px;">{{formatNum(fetch.gross)}}</td>
                     

                    <template v-for="(disp, index) in fetch.deduction">   --> CHILD ARRAY
                     <td>{{disp.amount}} <button type="button" @click="removeDeduction(index)"class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button> </td>
                     </template>
                   
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
```

> This function is not working ...  I hope u can help me

```
   removeDeduction(index) {
          return this.payrollPayableArray.reduce((acc,item)=>{
           const arr =  Object.values(item.deduction).reduce((bcc,a,idx)=>{
            Object.values(idx).splice(index,1)
          
           })
        
           })

           
         },
```

my problem is similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/uLqfks3e/5/

Comment: your reduce methods does not return your accumulator `acc`

Comment: `.splice` changes an array in-place, but `Object.values(..)` creates a new array, which happens first. Which means your code is discarding the result of the splice command. In addition, `idx` is a number; `Object.values(3)` produces nothing.

Comment: you want remove specifig element in nested array. correct ?

Comment: @robert yes exactly

Comment: Removing a specific element is best done using `.filter`; show a minimal example of input and desired output.

Comment: do you have index of parrent array and index in child array of  element to remove ?

Comment: @ChrisG ca you give me the code I have no idea how to do it I'm a begginer

Comment: can you show sample data of you  array ? how is data structured ?

Comment: @robert Yes I have

Comment: One problem is that you need to use `count` to pick the specific payroll array element first. Here's one possible way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/3cgb7fpL/

Comment: Hehe, yeah, it does :) Here's a `reduce` version: https://jsfiddle.net/0Ldot75f/ (note that the callback returns the accumulator)